# Can't get files from Server with "WindowsIdentityImpersonateMethod"

Tags: c#, .net, server

I know that that there sems to be a lot of question about Impersonate but I can't find right answer or a direction where to search for a solution to my problem.

I am trying to copy files from Server on my WM where I run my code.
I have used this "WindowsIdentityImpersonateMethod" that seams to work for most of the people just fine.

For me works just fine when I want to Impersonate  another user on my WM.
But for Impersonating user on Server that is on different Domaine, it doesn't work.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Security.Principal;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

namespace WindowsIdentityImpersonateMethodWithDelegate
{
  public enum LogonType
  {
    LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2,
    LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3,
    LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH = 4,
    LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE = 5,
    LOGON32_LOGON_UNLOCK = 7,
    LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8, // Win2K or higher
    LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9 // Win2K or higher
  };

  public enum LogonProvider
  {
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0,
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT35 = 1,
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40 = 2,
    LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 = 3
  };



public sealed class SafeTokenHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
  {
    private SafeTokenHandle()
        : base(true)
    {
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
      return CloseHandle(handle);
    }
  }

  public class ImpersonationHelper
  {
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out SafeTokenHandle phToken);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    /// <summary>
    /// Impersonates the specified domain name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="domainName">Name of the domain.</param>
    /// <param name="userName">Name of the user.</param>
    /// <param name="userPassword">The user password.</param>
    /// <param name="actionToExecute">The action to execute.</param>
    /// <exception cref="System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception"></exception>
    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]

    public void Impersonate(string domainName, string userName, string userPassword, Action actionToExecute)
    {
      SafeTokenHandle safeTokenHandle;

      try
      {

        const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
        //This parameter causes LogonUser to create a primary token.
        const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;

        // Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token.

        bool returnValue = LogonUser(userName, domainName, userPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out safeTokenHandle);  //returns false
        //bool returnValue1 = LogonUser(userName, domainName, userPassword, 9, 3, 
          //out safeTokenHandle); // return always true, even when userName ist wrong

        if (returnValue == false)
        {
          int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
          throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
        }

        using (safeTokenHandle)
        {

          // Use the token handle returned by LogonUser.
          using (WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
          {
            using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate())
            {
              bool test = File.Exists(@"\\10.29.14.05\c$\test.xml");  //always false, file is acessible from start->run
              bool test5 = Directory.Exists(@"\\10.99.10.25\c$\"); //false
              bool test1 = File.Exists(@"C:\test.xml"); //false
              Console.WriteLine("After impersonation: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);  //always local user
              actionToExecute();
            }
          }

        }

      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My user have all rights and its goes something like this.

```
string domain = "10.29.14.05";
string user = @"testtest\user1";
string password = "password!";
```

As you can see in code, I user two different Logntypes and LogonProviders.

```
bool returnValue = LogonUser(userName, domainName, userPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out safeTokenHandle);  //returns false
```

When I use this line.
 I get an Exception
System.ComponnentModel-Win32Exception 
"The username or password is incorrect"

```
bool returnValue1 = LogonUser(userName, domainName, userPassword, 9, 3, out safeTokenHandle);
```

When I use this line,LogonUser method always return TRUE, even when userName ist wrong.

And this line ist always local user

```
Console.WriteLine("After impersonation: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
```

And the three test variables always return false

```
bool test = File.Exists(@"\\10.29.14.05\c$\test.xml");  //always false, file is accessible from start->run
bool test5 = Directory.Exists(@"\\10.99.10.25\c$\"); //false
bool test1 = File.Exists(@"C:\test.xml"); //false
```

How to solve this problem?
Direction where to search or anything will be from help, thanks.

Comment: Have a look to my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444965/copy-and-paste-a-folder-programmaticaly-inside-a-mapped-network-drive/41445203#41445203 . May be it will be helpfull to you

Comment: @Sasha thanks, I will try your way. I will write my feedback soon.

Comment: @Sasha thanks very much. I have tried your code and it works :)

Comment: @Nice to here. But it is not my code :)