# Copy and paste a folder programmaticaly inside a mapped network drive

Tags: c#

I'm trying to copy a folder (not a file but an entire directory) on a mapped network drive and paste a new version of it with a different name in the same location. This code below works great if I'm using a local drive; however, I'm getting an authentication error when using a network drive.

```
DirectoryCopy(@"\\mappedserver\test", @"\\mappedserver\test2", true);
```

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The user name or password is incorrect."

I used the following MSDN documentation: [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914(v=vs.110).aspx) and modified it slightly to fit my needs.

```
    private static void DirectoryCopy(
    string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

        // If the source directory does not exist, throw an exception.
        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
                + sourceDirName);
        }

        // If the destination directory does not exist, create it.
        if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
        }


        // Get the file contents of the directory to copy.
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();

        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            // Create the path to the new copy of the file.
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);

            // Copy the file.
            file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
        }

        // If copySubDirs is true, copy the subdirectories.
        if (copySubDirs)
        {

            foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
            {
                // Create the subdirectory.
                string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);

                // Copy the subdirectories.
                DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
            }
        }
    }
```

A popular solution seems to be giving the folders full access permissions but unfortunately this has not made a difference.

How can I provide a username and password? I wouldn't really want to put an admin username and password in the application anywhere so how can this be done? My searches have come up mostly empty.

Comment: What is the user (or the user context) of the user running the application? I would begin to investigate in that direction...

Comment: Each of the users have full permissions to read/write/modify files and folders on the mapped network drive when their user accounts are setup. I've tried running VS and the program as an administrator but as I'm providing a username or password it has not done anything (not totally unexpected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I needed to copy file from remote PC. I have found this class:

```
public class NetworkShareAccesser : IDisposable
{
    private string _remoteUncName;
    private string _remoteComputerName;

    private string RemoteComputerName
    {
        get { return _remoteComputerName; }
        set
        {
            _remoteComputerName = value;
            _remoteUncName = @"\\" + _remoteComputerName;
        }
    }

    private string UserName { get; set; }
    private string Password { get; set; }

    #region Consts

    private const int RESOURCE_CONNECTED = 0x00000001;
    private const int RESOURCE_GLOBALNET = 0x00000002;
    private const int RESOURCE_REMEMBERED = 0x00000003;

    private const int RESOURCETYPE_ANY = 0x00000000;
    private const int RESOURCETYPE_DISK = 0x00000001;
    private const int RESOURCETYPE_PRINT = 0x00000002;

    private const int RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GENERIC = 0x00000000;
    private const int RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_DOMAIN = 0x00000001;
    private const int RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SERVER = 0x00000002;
    private const int RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHARE = 0x00000003;
    private const int RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_FILE = 0x00000004;
    private const int RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GROUP = 0x00000005;

    private const int RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE = 0x00000001;
    private const int RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER = 0x00000002;


    private const int CONNECT_INTERACTIVE = 0x00000008;
    private const int CONNECT_PROMPT = 0x00000010;
    private const int CONNECT_REDIRECT = 0x00000080;
    private const int CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE = 0x00000001;
    private const int CONNECT_COMMANDLINE = 0x00000800;
    private const int CONNECT_CMD_SAVECRED = 0x00001000;

    private const int CONNECT_LOCALDRIVE = 0x00000100;

    #endregion

    #region Errors

    private const int NO_ERROR = 0;

    private const int ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED = 5;
    private const int ERROR_ALREADY_ASSIGNED = 85;
    private const int ERROR_BAD_DEVICE = 1200;
    private const int ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME = 67;
    private const int ERROR_BAD_PROVIDER = 1204;
    private const int ERROR_CANCELLED = 1223;
    private const int ERROR_EXTENDED_ERROR = 1208;
    private const int ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS = 487;
    private const int ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = 87;
    private const int ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD = 1216;
    private const int ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234;
    private const int ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259;
    private const int ERROR_NO_NET_OR_BAD_PATH = 1203;
    private const int ERROR_NO_NETWORK = 1222;

    private const int ERROR_BAD_PROFILE = 1206;
    private const int ERROR_CANNOT_OPEN_PROFILE = 1205;
    private const int ERROR_DEVICE_IN_USE = 2404;
    private const int ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED = 2250;
    private const int ERROR_OPEN_FILES = 2401;

    #endregion

    #region PInvoke Signatures

    [DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetUseConnection(
        IntPtr hwndOwner,
        NETRESOURCE lpNetResource,
        string lpPassword,
        string lpUserID,
        int dwFlags,
        string lpAccessName,
        string lpBufferSize,
        string lpResult
        );

    [DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2(
        string lpName,
        int dwFlags,
        bool fForce
        );

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private class NETRESOURCE
    {
        public int dwScope = 0;
        public int dwType = 0;
        public int dwDisplayType = 0;
        public int dwUsage = 0;
        public string lpLocalName = "";
        public string lpRemoteName = "";
        public string lpComment = "";
        public string lpProvider = "";
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a NetworkShareAccesser for the given computer name. The user will be promted to enter credentials
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="remoteComputerName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static NetworkShareAccesser Access(string remoteComputerName)
    {
        return new NetworkShareAccesser(remoteComputerName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a NetworkShareAccesser for the given computer name using the given domain/computer name, username and password
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="remoteComputerName"></param>
    /// <param name="domainOrComuterName"></param>
    /// <param name="userName"></param>
    /// <param name="password"></param>
    public static NetworkShareAccesser Access(string remoteComputerName, string domainOrComuterName, string userName, string password)
    {
        return new NetworkShareAccesser(remoteComputerName, domainOrComuterName + @"\" + userName, password);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a NetworkShareAccesser for the given computer name using the given username (format: domainOrComputername\Username) and password
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="remoteComputerName"></param>
    /// <param name="userName"></param>
    /// <param name="password"></param>
    public static NetworkShareAccesser Access(string remoteComputerName, string userName, string password)
    {
        return new NetworkShareAccesser(remoteComputerName, userName, password);
    }

    private NetworkShareAccesser(string remoteComputerName)
    {
        RemoteComputerName = remoteComputerName;

        ConnectToShare(_remoteUncName, null, null, true);
    }

    private NetworkShareAccesser(string remoteComputerName, string userName, string password)
    {
        RemoteComputerName = remoteComputerName;
        UserName = userName;
        Password = password;

        ConnectToShare(_remoteUncName, UserName, Password, false);
    }

    private void ConnectToShare(string remoteUnc, string username, string password, bool promptUser)
    {
        NETRESOURCE nr = new NETRESOURCE
        {
            dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK,
            lpRemoteName = remoteUnc
        };

        if (promptUser)
        {
            WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, "", "", CONNECT_INTERACTIVE | CONNECT_PROMPT, null, null, null);
        }
        else
        {
            WNetUseConnection(IntPtr.Zero, nr, password, username, 0, null, null, null);
        }
    }

    private void DisconnectFromShare(string remoteUnc)
    {
        WNetCancelConnection2(remoteUnc, CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE, false);          
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <filterpriority>2</filterpriority>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        DisconnectFromShare(_remoteUncName);
    }
}
```

It will help you to connect with remote pc when you have it's credentials. You can use it so:

```
 using (NetworkShareAccesser.Access("1.1.1.1","domain","login","password"))
{
     //Here you have access to remote pc and you can perform your actions
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Worked like a charm! That is exactly what I was looking for - A way to auth credentials with a remote pc and perform a select set of actions. Where did you find that class? I searched for most of the morning and came up empty.

Comment: @A1raa, good that it was what you were looking for. I have found it few years ago, so I am afraid I donno yet, where it was.

Comment: Wow this is great, but unfortunately not working in an azure web app